# python webscrape cleaning

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

I am using python with beautifulsoup to capture and print out the following:
Small
5' x 10'
Outside unit/Drive-up access
$56/mo.
$70 In-store

I managed to get it to print out the unit size (Small) and unit type (outside unit/drive-up access) correctly, however, the others are printing out the proper data along with "div class text."

Anyone know how I can correctly grab it properly?
I will add my following code;

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#setting my_url to the wesite
my_url = 'https://www.publicstorage.com/north-carolina/self-storage-
charlotte-nc/28206-self-storage/2334?
lat=35.23552&lng=-80.83296&clp=1&sp=Charlotte|35.2270869|-80.8431267&ismi=1'

#Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#naming uClient to page_html
page_html = uClient.read()

#closing uClient
uClient.close()

#this does my html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#setting container to capture where the actual info is using inspect element
#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"srp_res_row plp"})

filename = "product.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "unit_size, size_dim, unit_type, online_price, reg_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.div.div
    unit_size = title_container.text
    size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label srp_font_14"})
    unit_container = container.li
    unit_type = unit_container.text
    online_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label alt-price"})
    reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"reg-price"})


    print("unit_size: " + str(unit_size))
    print("size_dim: " + str(size_dim))
    print("unit_type: " + str(unit_type))
    print("online_price: " + str(online_price))
    print("reg_price: " + str(reg_price))

    f.write(str(unit_size) + "," +str(size_dim) + "," +str(unit_type) + "," 
    +str(online_price) + "," +str(reg_price) + "\n")
f.close()
```

```html
<li class="srp_res_row plp">
    <div class="srp_res_clm srp_clm160">
        <div class="srp_label plp">Small</div>
        <div class="srp_v-space_3"></div>
        <div class="srp_label srp_font_14" style="padding-left: 5px;">5' x 10'</div>
        <div class="srp_v-space_3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="srp_res_clm srp_clm120">
        <ul class="srp_list">
            <li>Outside unit/Drive-up access</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="srp_res_clm srp_clm90">
        <div class="srp_label">$1<span class="srp_label_symbol">†</span></div>
        <div class="srp_v-space_10">1st Month</div>
    </div>
    <div class="srp_res_clm srp_clm90">
        <div class="srp_label alt-price">$56/mo.</div>
        <div class="online-special">Online Special<span class="srp_label_symbol">†</span></div>
        <div class="srp_v-space_15"></div>
        <div class="reg-price">$70 In-store</div>
    </div>
    <div class="srp_res_clm srp_clm100 srp_vcenter"><a class="srp_continue unit-no-deposit" data-deposit-amount="0" data-deposit-days="0" data-features="Outside unit/Drive-up access" data-marketing-size="5x10" data-ppk="altproduct_price" data-promotionid="132" data-siteid="2334" data-size-description="5' x 10'" data-sizeid="613573" data-wc2-unit="false" href="/ReservationDetails.aspx?st=2334&amp;sz=613573&amp;key=[rnd]&amp;location=&amp;plp=1&amp;rk=&amp;ismi=1&amp;sp=Charlotte%7c35.2270869%7c-80.8431267&amp;clp=1"><img alt="Continue" src="/images/srp-cont-new-80.png" style="width: 80px; height: 32px"/></a></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_all` returns a ResultSet object which you can iterate over using a for loop.

Try this code :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#setting my_url to the wesite
my_url = 'https://www.publicstorage.com/north-carolina/self-storage-charlotte-nc/28206-self-storage/2334?lat=35.23552&lng=-80.83296&clp=1&sp=Charlotte|35.2270869|-80.8431267&ismi=1'

#Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#naming uClient to page_html
page_html = uClient.read()

#closing uClient
uClient.close()

#this does my html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#setting container to capture where the actual info is using inspect element
#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"srp_res_row plp"})

filename = "product.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "unit_size, size_dim, unit_type, online_price, reg_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.div.div
    unit_size = title_container.text
    size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label srp_font_14"})
    unit_container = container.li
    unit_type = unit_container.text
    online_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label alt-price"})
    reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"reg-price"})



    print("unit_size: " + str(unit_size))
    print("size_dim: {}".format("".join(list(i.text for i in size_dim))))  #edited line
    print("unit_type: " + str(unit_type))
    print("Online Price: {}".format("".join(list(i.text for i in online_price)))) #edited line
    print("Online Price: {}".format("".join(list(i.text for i in reg_price)))) #edited line


    f.write(str(unit_size) + "," +str(size_dim) + "," +str(unit_type) + ","
    +str(online_price) + "," +str(reg_price) + "\n")
f.close()
```

output:

```
unit_size: Small
size_dim: 5' x 10'
unit_type: Outside unit/Drive-up access
Online Price: $52/mo.
Online Price: $64 In-store
unit_size: Medium
size_dim: 5' x 15'
unit_type: Outside unit/Drive-up access
Online Price: $80/mo.
Online Price: $100 In-store
```

> Updated code as per comments :

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


#setting my_url to the wesite
my_url = 'https://www.publicstorage.com/north-carolina/self-storage-charlotte-nc/28206-self-storage/2334?lat=35.23552&lng=-80.83296&clp=1&sp=Charlotte|35.2270869|-80.8431267&ismi=1'

#Opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)

#naming uClient to page_html
page_html = uClient.read()

#closing uClient
uClient.close()

#this does my html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#setting container to capture where the actual info is using inspect element
#grabs each product
containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"srp_res_row plp"})

filename = "product.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "unit_size, size_dim1, unit_type, online_price, reg_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.div.div
    unit_size = title_container.text
    size_dim = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label srp_font_14"})
    unit_container = container.li
    unit_type = unit_container.text
    online_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"srp_label alt-price"})
    reg_price = container.findAll("div", {"class":"reg-price"})


    for item in zip(unit_size,size_dim,unit_container,online_price,reg_price):
        csv=item[0] + "," + item[1].text + "," + item[2] + "," + item[3].text + "," + item[4].text + "\n"
        f.write(csv)
```

Comment: Paul, this prints it properly but does not do so in the excel file that it creates. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @D-Ru because you are not storing that output which is coming from my edited code , you are storing old output which was not correct.

Comment: @Paul, I'm sorry, I'm quite new to this but how would I store the new output? I'm assuming the loop is capturing the old output.

Comment: @D-Ru do you want to print and store both things or if you have to direct store the output then why you are printing it on the terminal ?

Comment: @Paul, storing it in excel is the main purpose. I am printing it on the terminal to get a quick look to see if it was capturing the correct data.

Comment: @D-Ru checkout updated code , if my solution solved your problem you can accept the answer.

Comment: @Paul, this looks great. Only thing I see that's strange is for unit_type, the output is just "O" and not Outside unit/Drive-up access. I appreciate your help in this.

Comment: @Paul, I realized this is only capturing the last unit size in the website and not gathering all the unit sizes. Did something break in the loop? As far as format, this looks perfect. I will be sure to check "answered" as soon as I hear back from you regarding this loop issue.

Comment: this may be my fault - I added some extra information to grab. You have answered the question. Thank you very much. I will attempt to fix what I have added to the code